# Typical text for forms vulnerability testing

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, xss

For an usual need, I was searching for a typical text block to try my HTML/PHP forms, and mail sent.

Currently, I use this one :

```
test "test"
çà ;: $€
<script>alert('test');</script>
```

It allows me to test :

- Special chars
- XSS vulnerability
- Issues with quotes
- line breaks

I wanna make this block evolve, that's why I'm asking if anybody uses a similar block, maybe more complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plenty of useful ones to try here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I don't wanna try only XSS vulnerability. My goal is have an all-in-one block, checking for most common problems.

Comment: In that case it depends on the purpose of your php script. If allowing HTML or Markdown for example, your requirements are going to be quite different. One size won't necessarily fit all, but I totally understand your reasons for compiling a "typical" list of naughty input.

Comment: I just wanna allow any kind of basic text, without any HTML. I use this block for user side forms (contact, booking...), not for stylised content.

Comment: you could use some penetration test tools

Comment: can you reccommend any easy / fool proof pen tools ?  I'd like to start testing parts of my web apps with devoting myself to Kali.